# How to stop telethon conversation on receiving a specific message

Tags: python, telethon

I have made a telegram bot using telethon library which takes reponses from user using `button.inline` and `button.text` methods. But I want to stop the conversation as soon as a specific message(like bye) is entered by the user.

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, pattern='Hi'))
async def main(event):
    global SENDER
    MSG = event.raw_text
    SENDER=event.chat_id

    async with bot.conversation(SENDER) as conv:
        await conv.send_message('choose', buttons=[[Button.inline('Yes'), Button.inline('No')] ])

        await conv.send_message('<b> Want More ? </b>', parse_mode='html', buttons=[ [Button.text('Yes', resize=True,single_use=True), Button.text('No', resize=True,single_use=True)], [Button.text('More', resize=True,single_use=True)] ] )
       ...
       ...
```

Whenever the user sends 'Hi', the bot starts querying using buttons.

In the [telethon docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#module-telethon.tl.custom.conversation) , `cancel()` and `cancel_all()` methods are provided. But how can I implement them such that on getting message bye, it ends the conversation ?

Comment: You would have a pattern for `'Bye'` that creates a `bot.conversation(SENDER)` and calls `cancel_all()` on it. Conversations are not really made for anything beyond very simple scenarios, and you will run into more limitations like this one if you keep using them.

Comment: I am using `Conversations` because it is easy to get the latest message/response from user and then act based on it. So far what I have read & understood from telethon docs, I know that If I had used events , It would not have been possible to proceed further in the chat with user. Because on receiving a new message, either I get to the start of the function of `event NewMessage` or move to a new event `NewMessage`.  Could you tell me How can I get the latest message/response in the middle of the function/code without using `Conversations`?

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, `conv.cancel_all()` cancels all conversations of that chat. I noticed I wasn't able to open more than one conversation, because default value `exclusive=True` was set.
So, what I did was:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda e: e.is_private))
async def handler(event):
    try:
        rawmsg = event.message.message
        if rawmsg == "/cancel":
            # set exclusive=False so we can still create a conversation, even when there's an existing (exclusive) one.
            async with client.conversation(await event.get_chat(), exclusive=False) as conv:
                await conv.cancel_all()
                await event.respond("Operation is cancelled.")
                return


        async with client.conversation(await event.get_chat(), exclusive=True) as conv:
            await conv.send_message("Hey, I'll send you back whatever you write! To cancel, do /cancel")
            while True:
                resp = (await conv.get_response()).raw_text
                await conv.send_message(resp)

#   except telethon.errors.common.AlreadyInConversationError:
#       pass
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

When there's a new message with text "/cancel", it will open a conversation, and call `.cancel_all()` to cancel the old conversation.